# Folder with space in name not recognized

Tags: bash, directory, space

i'm very new to stackoverflow and to bash/python scripting.

I'm in need to resize some Data Terrain Model files (300+) in .tif format to be able to convert 'em into .hgt and i'm able to do it all using gdal tool but only per single file at once.
Guess you alredy spotted where scripting comes in: need to automatize the process for the 300+ files!

So i started looking a bit about how bash works and came out with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "'/home/fenix/1\ Vari\ HDD/MTB/DTM\ Alos/'"*.tif; do
    PATH=/usr/bin/ gdalwarp -of Gtiff -ts 3601 3601 $filename.tif "'/home/fenix/1\ Vari\ HDD/MTB/DTM Alos/temp/'"$filename.tif
done
```

I always used the backslash to move into "spaced" name directories or files but seems not working with scripting.... googleing i found using quotes or double quotes would fix it but still no success

As you have seen in the code above i used double quote, quote and backslash alone and any combination of the 3 but i'm always getting

> ERROR 4: '/home/fenix/1: No such file or directory

Why?!?!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

EDIT:
Following tripleee golden suggestions i edited the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin/
for filename in "/home/fenix/1 Vari HDD/MTB/DTM Alos/"*.tif; do
    gdalwarp -of Gtiff -ts 3601 3601 "$filename" "/home/fenix/1 Vari HDD/MTB/DTM Alos/temp/${filename##*/}"
done
```

And worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your excessive quoting is getting in the way.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "/home/fenix/1 Vari HDD/MTB/DTM Alos/"*.tif; do
    PATH=/usr/bin/ gdalwarp -of Gtiff -ts 3601 3601 "$filename" "${filename##*/}"
done
```

The string `/home/fenix/stuff with spaces` can be expressed as either of

```
/home/fenix/stuff\ with\ spaces
"/home/fenix/stuff with spaces"
'/home/fenix/stuff with spaces'
```

A backslash or quote within quotes produces a literal backslash or quote, as part of the quoted string. A backslashed backslash or quote similarly produces a literal backslash or quote.

Single quotes are stronger; everything between them is literal. Double quotes allow for variable and backtick expansion, and backslash quoting.

So  `"'/home/fenix/1\ Vari\ HDD/MTB/DTM\ Alos/'"` refers to `./'/home/fenix/1\ Vari\ HDD/MTB/DTM\ Alos/` which probably isn't a valid path, unless the current directory contains a directory whose name is literally a single quote, etc (where I put in the leading `./` just to make this more explicit).

Perhaps a complication is that the quotes inhibit wildcard expansion; so the wildcard `*.tif` needs to be unquoted. (Well, strictly speaking, only the wildcard needs to be unquoted; `*'.tif'` or `*".tif"` or `*\.\t\i\f` would work, too.)

Notice also that the value of `$filename` is the full path to each expanded value of the wildcard, with no directory prefix or extension suffix trimmed off or any other magic like that. I have speculatively shown how to pass the last argument as the filename with the directory path trimmed off (the parameter substitution `${variable##pattern}` retrieves the value of `variable` with any prefix matching `pattern` trimmed off). So the output file should land in the current directory, with inp^t from the wildcard match (hopefully then in a different directory, so you don't end up overwriting your input files).

Finally, observe how we take care to always use double quotes around variables which contain file names. (Failing to do this is a common error even in some fairly popular tutorials. The script will appear to work until you try to handle file names with irregular spacing or literal asterisks, etc.)

The wacky `PATH` assignment looks weird, too. Does `gdalwarp` execute external commands, and do you really then want it to only find external commands in `/usr/bin`? Or perhaps you mean to run `/usr/bin/gdalwarp` (though setting the correct `PATH` at the beginning of the script would arguably be better than hardcoding a specific absolute pathname).

Comment: I've not completely understood why i needed this but to make the script (gdalscript.sh placed in my home dir) to be found i had to change the PATH of the bash interface (using KDE environment Konsole) pointing to my home dir then everything launched from here and everything launched from "inside" the script did refer to the same PATH so to make bash to find the program "gdalwarp" i had to point again to gdalwarp installation directory (/usr/bin/ indeed)

Comment: You can add stuff to your PATH with `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` which preserves the old value after the colon. I'm guessing you meant to write `./scriptfile` instead of just `scriptfile` and then you don't need to mess with your PATH at all.